# Error Converting Epoch to DateTime in SQL Server when epoch is more than a Trillion seconds

Tags: sql-server, datetime, epoch

I tried out many answers already given for converting EPOCH to SQL Server datetime. They work when the EPOCH  has up to a billion seconds. But as soon as it crosses the Trillion mark it goes bust! E.g. -->

```
1. SELECT dateadd(MCS,1351187877744,'1970-01-01')
2. SELECT dateadd(NS,1351187877744,'1970-01-01')
3. SELECT dateadd(NANOSECOND, 1351187877744, '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0000000')
4. SELECT convert(bigint, datediff(ss, '01-01-1970 00:00:00',1351187877744))
```

All the above fail with the following overflow error:
"Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int."

Interestingly when I input this date on [this site](http://www.epochconverter.com/#tools) it returns the correct values.

Any suggestions how to do this in a way that works for EPOCHs which are of any magnitude (>trillion secs etc)

Comment: Mitch, that converts to "GMT:Thu, 25 Oct 2012 17:57:57 UTC" which is the correct value it should convert to. I think that the problem has something to do with the precision as even a billion seconds are sufficient to get this date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one -

**MSDN :**

DATEADD: *The number argument cannot exceed the range of int. In the following statements, the argument for number exceeds the range of int by 1. The following error message is returned: "**Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1. Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int."***

**Query:**

```
DECLARE 
      @Date DATETIME = '19700101'
    , @MaxInt INT = 2147483647 
    , @ms BIGINT = 1351187877744

WHILE @ms != 0 BEGIN

    SELECT @Date = DATEADD(ms, CASE WHEN @ms > @MaxInt THEN @MaxInt ELSE @ms END, @Date)
    SELECT @ms = CASE WHEN @ms - @MaxInt < 0 THEN 0 ELSE @ms - @MaxInt END

END

SELECT @Date
```

**Output:**

```
2012-10-25 17:57:57.533
```

Comment: Thanks Devart! A very elegant Solution indeed!

Answer (score 2):

Simply create this function

```
CREATE FUNCTION convertEpoch 
(@epochVal bigint) RETURNS datetime 
AS BEGIN DECLARE @Return datetime
SELECT @return = dateadd(s,@epochVal/1000,'1970-01-01')
RETURN @return END
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) the syntax is :

```
DATEADD (datepart , number , date )
```

where 
*number*
Is an expression that can be resolved to an `int` that is added to a datepart of date. User-defined variables are valid.

Also,
Addition for a datepart of `microsecond` or `nanosecond` for date data types `smalldatetime`, `date`, and `datetime` is **not allowed**.

Try this :

```
DECLARE @datetime2 datetime2 = '2007-01-01 13:10:10.1111111';

SELECT '50 nanoseconds', DATEADD(nanosecond,50,@datetime2)
```

Comment: The problem is that this syntax fails when the magnitude is in Nanoseconds. Already tried this syntax if u see the question (points 1,2 & 3). nevertheless thanks for the response!