# EPOCH timestamp from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I feel like I've read a ton of these corresponding posts such as,

[converting Epoch timestamp to sql server(human readable format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787827/converting-epoch-timestamp-to-sql-serverhuman-readable-format)

& [How do I convert a SQL server timestamp to an epoch timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47397350/how-do-i-convert-a-sql-server-timestamp-to-an-epoch-timestamp)

But can't seem to get my particular use-case working.  I need to convert an epoch timestamp to a normal date/time value.  Currently, the column is a nvarchar(max) type.  Here's an example of one of the dates:

```
1478563200000
```

I'm trying to get it to look like the following:

```
2019-01-14 00:00:00.0000000
```

I've tried the following to no success all with the same error message:

```
select DATEADD(SS, CONVERT(BIGINT, baddate), '19700101') as gooddate
from table
```

**"Arithmatic overflow error converting expression to data type int"**

I've tried minutes, seconds, days, all same error message and at this point I'm about to tell the guys to send the data in a different format.

Comment: Your problem is the `Convert(BIGINT....)` where you need and `int`. Convert to `bigint`, then divide by 1000 (trading in ms resolution for s resolution) and then convert to `int`. Why is the column of type `nvarchar(max)` in the first place? Why isn't it a numeric type (...like `int`)?

Comment: What are the values of `baddate` in the `table`? Can you show example? Maybe put on a rextester.com wall?

Comment: @DavidG I never said BIGINT is no numeric type, I said why the **column** is of type nvarchar (which isn't a numeric type).

Comment: @DavidG Yes it did; though I changed the first two sentences after I realized why the bigint was used instead of int (the timestamp is in milliseconds). The part about the type still stands and is unchanged.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Converting Epoch to DateTime in SQL Server when epoch is more than a Trillion seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728211/error-converting-epoch-to-datetime-in-sql-server-when-epoch-is-more-than-a-trill)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Epoch conversion to DateTime in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53767909/epoch-conversion-to-datetime-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
select DATEADD(SS, CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(BIGINT, baddate)/1000), '19700101') as gooddate
from table
```

DATEADD expects an `int`, not a `bigint`. Since your timestamp is in milliseconds, it won't "fit" in an `int`. If you trade-in millisecond resolution for second resolution by dividing by 1000 it will fit in an integer and make `DATEADD` happy. So first we convert the `NVARCHAR` to `BIGINT` (why store as `NVARCHAR` in the first place?), then divide by 1000 and then convert to `INT`.

Another option is to divide the value by 1000 at the time of insert (and, again, make the column an int in the first place). That'll save a lot of `CONVERT`s everywhere (you can get rid of them all) and probably speed up your queries quite nicely. Then again, you could even convert the column to `datetime` (or `datetime2` or whatever type is best suited) and leave out the entire dateadd/convert mess in your queries alltogether. Always try to get your data ad close to the final datatype you need it in later.

---

Edit: I just realized you can probably leave one `convert` out:

```
select DATEADD(SS, CONVERT(BIGINT, baddate)/1000, '19700101') as gooddate
from table
```

This is the same as the original suggestion, only this time the cast to `int` is implicit. But converting your data upon insert is still probably the better idea. So the rest of my post still stands.

Comment: Dang, just needed to switch the bigint out.  I do agree that the column being in NVARCHAR is kind of a pain to deal with but ultimately I believe it has to do with how the process in upserting the records.  It's coming from an outside vendor so it's a bit out of my scope.

Comment: Note, this works only for years in range 1902 through 2038.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the correct result to the millisecond, that works with years 0001 through 9999, using the accepted answer

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53767909/epoch-conversion-to-datetime-in-sql/53786143#53786143).

```
declare @x nvarchar(max) = N'1478563200000'

select dbo.UnixTimeToDateTime2(@x)
```